# cts query to find unique values from a field from json document in Marklogic staging

Tags: javascript, marklogic

I'm trying to write a JavaScript cts query to query only unique values from a key from a JSON document based on another key. i.e, similar to a query like: `select distinct(name) from data-hub-staging where source='source1'`

```
{
    "source": "source1",
    "name": "John",
    "DOB": "1-01-1990",
    "load_date": "2021-10-23 10:23:55"
},
{
    "source": "source1",
    "name": "John",
    "DOB": "1-01-1990",
    "load_date": "2021-10-24 10:23:55"
},
{
    "source": "source1",
    "name": "Mark",
    "DOB": "1-01-1990",
    "load_date": "2021-10-24 10:23:55"
}
```

I have been trying the below query, but it returns all the fields. I wanted only the unique *name* field.

```
const query = cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery(
              "source",
              "source1");

[...new Set (cts.search(query)
.toArray()
  .map(doc => doc.root.name).sort())]
```

```
Current result: [John,John,Mark]
Expected result: [John,Mark]
```

Comment: this is returning an array of the `name` values for me. Can you double check your results, or provide an example of the current output and the desired output?

Comment: I modified the question with the expected result

Comment: okay, so your JSON document has an array of objects. I was testing with several different JSON documents.

Comment: Sorry it has several JSON documents. My bad. it is in Marklogic staging

Comment: So, each JSON document is a single object with the `name` property. You don't have a JSON doc that is an array of objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `name` values are not being de-duplicated by the Set because they are `text()` nodes. You need to get the [`.valueOf()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/Node.valueOf) those text nodes and then the strings will be de-duplicated.

```
const query = cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery(
              "source",
              "source1");

[...new Set (cts.search(query)
.toArray()
  .map(doc => doc.root.name.valueOf()).sort())]
```